# Symfony: many projects in many different domains

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, virtual-hosts

I'm learning Symfony right now. I created 2 Symfony projects with 2 different domains. Nevertheless, my second domain points to the first, and don't know why.

I'm following this tutorial, the famous jobeet: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1 ... rine/en/01

Notice my configurations:

My /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
ServerName localhost

#From the symfony tutorial "jobeet"
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080

# This is the configuration for your project
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
 ServerName www.jobeet.com.localhost
 DocumentRoot "/home/lola/sfprojects/jobeet/web"
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 <Directory "/home/lola/sfprojects/jobeet/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
 </Directory>
 Alias /sf /home/lola/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
<Directory "/home/lola/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
   Allow from All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#Another symfony tutorial
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8081

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerName www.tutorial.com.localhost
DocumentRoot "/home/sfprojects/tutorial/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/tutorial/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
  Alias /sf /home/lola/sfprojects/tutorial/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/lola/sfprojects/tutorial/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Notice** that I'm listening to **8081** port in the **tutorial** domain. I tried the permutation of VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:**80** and VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:**81**. Neither worked. (really don't know which use)

My /etc/hosts:

```
#From the symfony tutorial
127.0.0.1 www.jobeet.com.localhost

#From ANOTHER symfony tutorial
127.0.0.1 www.tutorial.com.localhost
```

After that I restarted Apache.

Now, when I do:
http://www.jobeet.com.localhost/frontend_dev.php/ I go to my Jobeet tutorial things, **BUT** when I do http://www.tutorial.com.localhost/frontend_dev.php/ I **ALSO** go to the Jobeet page. I should go to the one containing the **tutorial** part.

Why is **not** working??!

Comment: it sounds more like a webserver (apache) problem....

Comment: It was my mistake. I will post after 8 hours -because my reputation in less than 100- So, for tomorrow, I will put the answer. Short one: NameVirtualHost must be called ONE time, like NameVirtualHost:80

Comment: May I suggest, if you're learning Symfony for the first time, that you learn Symfony2 instead. Symfony 1 will no longer be supported as of a year from now.

Comment: Thank you! In fact I'm learning both! Never the less, the projects of the company I'm working for are in 1.4. They do not want to migrate to 2 because the fears of breaking the system (is HUGE, and gives services to half a continent). So, I have no option right now :/

Answer (score 1):

Well:

In /etc/apache2/httpd.conf is enough with:

```
 NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
```

I repeated this command when creating the other *ServeName* (**tutorial**). Maybe that was the conflict. I left all in port **80**. Now it resolve right.

So, this is the final /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
ServerName localhost

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

# This is the configuration for your project
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
 ServerName www.jobeet.com.localhost
 DocumentRoot "/home/lola/sfprojects/jobeet/web"
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 <Directory "/home/lola/sfprojects/jobeet/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
 </Directory>
 Alias /sf /home/lola/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
<Directory "/home/lola/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#Another symfony tutorial
# DO NOT REPEAT NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 --------> ****HERE: do not repeat this****

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerName www.tutorial.com.localhost
DocumentRoot "/home/sfprojects/tutorial/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/tutorial/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
  Alias /sf /home/lola/sfprojects/tutorial/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/lola/sfprojects/tutorial/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

The /etc/hosts (or in /etc/apache2/sites-avaiable for debian) is the same.

I can access to www.jobeet.com.localhost and www.tutorial.com.localhost

Sorry, it was my misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

1. A common mistake is to have disabled the virtual host module for apache, for enable it try: `sudo a2enmod virtualhost`
2. put your vhost conf in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/name-file-with-vhost-conf`
3. all virtual host must be enabled, with `sudo a2ensite name-file-with-vhost-conf`
4. apache2 must be reloaded `sudo service apache2 reload`

you can try this [github/rokemaster/virtual_hosts](https://github.com/rokemaster/virtual_hosts) is all steps in one script

Comment: there would be a difference doing it in the `/sites-aviables rather` than in the `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: `/sites-available/`is a place where apache read configuration about vhost and `/etc/hosts` file is a static DNS for the OS and is necesary for the properly function of virtual host